# comparing values from dictionary with same key python

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

Below is a dictionary called total_per_person that maps total spent by a person in one week

```
{'Edith': 79.24, 'Carol': 176.05, 'Hannah': 90.45, 'Frank': 66.6, 'Alice': 64.10, 'Ingrid': 59.45, 'Bob': 103.50, 'Gertrude': 107.45, 'Dave': 62.24}
```

Below is another dictionary called name_to_budget that maps the weekly budget of a person:

```
{'Alice': 62.12, 'Bob': 40.34, 'Carol': 46.69, 'Dave': 37.79, 'Edith': 95.39, 'Frank': 32.87, 'Gertrude': 29.13, 'Hannah': 24.21, 'Ingrid': 91.19}
```

How do I compare the values and decide if they were over or under budget? Should I make a function so its easier?

Comment: Have you tried to write the *function* first - can you share the code? and where do you run into  issues?

Comment: something to consider: can you guarantee that the first dictionary will always have a corresponding entry in the second dictionary? Can you guarantee that the second dictionary will always have a corresponding entry in the first dictionary? What do you want to do if you cannot make these guarantees?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the keys and compare each one on the two dicts.
`dict.keys()` return a list with all the keys.

This code snippets also consider corresponding  budget and make sure the key is in the second dict with the `in` operator.

```py
total_per_person = {'Edith': 79.24, 'Carol': 176.05, 'Hannah': 90.45, 'Frank': 66.6, 'Alice': 64.10, 'Ingrid': 59.45, 'Bob': 103.50, 'Gertrude': 107.45, 'Dave': 62.24, 'Alex': 12.12}

name_to_budget = {'Alice': 62.12, 'Bob': 40.34, 'Carol': 46.69, 'Dave': 37.79, 'Edith': 95.39, 'Frank': 32.87, 'Gertrude': 29.13, 'Hannah': 24.21, 'Ingrid': 91.19}

compared_to_budget = {}

for key in total_per_person.keys():
    if key not in name_to_budget:
        compared_to_budget[key] = "missing" # Not in name_to_budget dict
        continue
    if total_per_person[key] == name_to_budget[key]:
        compared_to_budget[key] = "same"
    elif total_per_person[key] < name_to_budget[key]:
        compared_to_budget[key] = "under"
    else:
        compared_to_budget[key] = "over"

print(compared_to_budget)
```

Comment: Why do you `break` after finding a missing key? I wouldn't consider that a fatal error that would prevent you from checking everybody else.

Comment: You are right. My fault. I've changed with `continue`

Comment: Another thing I just noticed, shouldn't your `>` be `<`?

Comment: Yes, I've changed